# Given a triangle and a square in a three-dimensional space, how to determine whether there is an intersecting line segment and find it?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, geometry

I know how to find the intersection of two planes in three-dimensional space, but what about a rectangle and a triangle?

for example, there is a rectangle ABCD and a triangle EFG.

Does calculating this require knowledge of graphics, such as ray casting? I don't know.

Comment: You can find intersection of 2 planes, as a line. If so, check whether the line intersects with the both shapes(square,triangle). Each check is 2D-problem because the line and shape is coplanar.